# How to get separeated ints from file in C

Tags: c, file, int, scanf

How can I get, in C, a separated int's from a file like "1, 2,,3,,,  5,6" (to an array or one by one) without getting the garbage like " " or ","?(`,,,` is a possible case)
I thought about `strtok` but it's only deals with strings, and I don't know what will be the length of the file, so maybe `fgets` isn't the solution..
I tried this:

```
   fp=fopen("temp.txt","r");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error");
        exit(0);
   }
   while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&num)!=EOF)
   {
      printf("first num is %d",&num);
   }
```

But I think it will be a problem because of the unknown file size and because of the garbage problem.
What do you think?

thanks!!

Comment: What is the structure of your file? can you post a sample file?

Comment: only numbers and spaces and ",". an example is "12,213   12,12312,,,32    ,,,12"

Comment: the function fscanf returns a count (0 or greater) of the number of successful input/conversion operations, not EOF.  in this example, it will return 1 when successful and 0 when not successful

Comment: and what fscanf will return on the end of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scanf()`'s return value

```
int chk;
do {
    chk = fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
    switch (chk) {
        default: /* EOF */;
                 break;
        case 0: fgetc(fp); /* ignore 1 character and retry */
                break;
        case 1: printf("num is %d\n", num);
                break;
    }
} while (chk >= 0);
```

Comment: the 'fgets' is for skipping over garbage?

Comment: `fgetc()` (with a lowercase C) reads one character, which necessarily isn't part of an integer or it would have been captured by the `scanf()`

Comment: fgetc** yeah sounds great...and what I will get on the end of the file?

Comment: At the end of file, the loop terminates

Comment: the chk gets a NULL on the EOF?

Comment: No, the `fscanf()` in the code above returns one of 3 values: `EOF`, `0`, or `1`. The switch statement behaves differently for each possible result.

Comment: this line: 'case 0: fgetc(fp);' needs to be: 'case 0: chk = fgetc(fp);' so the chk is updated at the end of loop while statement

Comment: @user3629249: not really. There's two things wrong with that: 1) resulting `chk` could have many many values, not only `EOF`, `0`, and `1`; 2) there always will be a character available for `fgetc()` when `scanf()` return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The program below works **for any format** of the file and which can extract **any integral number** contained there

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* f=fopen("file","rb");
    /* open the file  */
    char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    /* str will store every line of the  file */
    if (f!=NULL)
    {
        printf("All the numbers found in the file !\n");
        while (fgets(str,100,f)!=NULL)
        {
            int i=0,n=0;
            /* the n will contain each number of the f ile  */
            for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
            {
                int test=0;
                /* test will tell us if a number was found or  not  */
                while (isdigit(str[i]) && i<strlen(str))
                {
                    test=1;
                    n=n*10+str[i]-'0';
                    i++;
                }
                if(test!=0)
                    printf("%d\n",n);
                /* print the number if it is found */
            }
        }


        fclose(f);
    }
    free(str);
    //free the space allocated once we finished
    return 0;
}
```

if our file is

```
Hell0a, How12
ARe 1You ?
I live in 245 street
```

it will generate

```
All the numbers found in the file !
0
12
1
245
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is the size of a pointer in the current implementation. I think you meant `100` in the line with the `fgets()` call.

Comment: yes right thanks ! @pgm :) maybe because I used to use the arrays ! thanks  again !